# The LO side of a Mosfet Half Bridge Gate Drive

Tags: mosfet-driver

[image]

I seem to have a discrepancy between what happens in my simulator and what is happening on my breadboard. In my simulator this configuration is an OFF mosfet however on my breadboard I set up up this configuration and I have on ON mosfet. Why might this be happening?

I added the 1k resistor to my breadboard it's still an ON mosfet on breadboard but not in sim.

I'm using some IRLZ34N's for mosfets on my board. My power supply is drawing about 0.8A I just crank up the volts slowly from 0.

Thank You!

Comment: I'm reading from International Rectifier. There is an on resistance. I'm curious about the off state.

Comment: an-1048 says there are gate on characteristics such as current max and voltage max. I there is something in that document about the off state, it didn't really stand out to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have wired it up in that simulation, there is a 1kOhm load being driven by an 11.9V power supply when the MOSFET is off. In that circuit when you turn the MOSFET on, it would short out the 11.9V power supply to ground. This seems a tad odd? It would be helpful if you posted a schematic of the exact circuit you have wired up.

Anyway, what is connected to the Gate of the MOSFET on your breadboard? If it is floating, you may find that it switches itself on if there is charge on the gate. This is especially likely if you had the gate connected to a voltage source and then unplugged the wire. In this situation you should have a resistor (10k to 100k or so) connected between the gate and source to ensure that the transistor is turned off.

Comment: That's a good point about the resistor between the gate and source. 
I think my schematic is good but probably the one I have needs improvement to be functional. 
It looks like if the VS not hooked up the IR2104 creates equality between VB and VS (Or VCC and VS I have to see block diagram). 
By lowering VS to ground I can control a small current from my power supply.

Comment: It has to be the right ground. For me it only works when I ground to my power supplies ground terminal pretty much directly. 
In my first prototype I built out a PCB that gets PWM on the fets. Tried it out with a little Oscilloscope saw my square waves. 
The power assemblies don't work though. I might make some minor changes to schematic.

Comment: I'm back to my breadboard because just driving the fets isn't the whole job. It has to run the charge loops as well.

Comment: I see what you mean about the short circuit. In the design its like that because VS line has to be Volts of the battery or it probably won't work at all. Is there some suggestion on what to do so it doesn't short. I'm working with a freechargecontroller design.

Comment: Yes the resistor between gate and source is a much better design. Thank you for answering the question.